# Pandas splitting of columns (dtype:list) followed by dynamic lookup/merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, lookup

I have a data frame which is as follows.

| Table_name | Domain | Use_case |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group | Reporting | finance, marketing |
| resource | Banking, Reporting | marketing, sales, finance |
| customer | Reporting | sales |

Domain_df[]:

| Domain_name | Domain_id |
| --- | --- |
| Reporting | 1001 |
| Banking | 1002 |

Usecase_df[]

| usecase_name | id |
| --- | --- |
| Finance | 2001 |
| marketing | 2002 |
| sales | 2003 |

Final result I want is:

| Table_name | Domain | Use_case | domain_id | usecase_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group | Reporting | finance, marketing | [1001] | [2001,2002] |
| resource | Banking,Reporting | marketing, sales, finance | [1002,1001] | [2002,2003,2001] |
| customer | Reporting | sales | [1002] | [2003] |

Intitially I tried splitting the column with delimiter , and forming separate columns using:

```
df=df.join(pandas.DataFrame(df['Verified Use case'].str.split(', ', expand=True)).add_prefix('use_case_'))
```

Result of which I got something like:

| Table_name | Domain | Use_case | domain0 | domain1 | usecase0 | usecase1 | usecase2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group | Reporting | finance, marketing | Reporting | NA | finance | marketing | NA |
| resource | Banking, Reporting | marketing, sales, finance | Banking | Reporting | marketing | sales | finance |
| customer | Reporting | sales | reporting | NA | sales | NA | NA |

Beyond this, I need to do a merge/lookup on ever column to the domain and use case tables to fetch the respective ids returned to the data frame in the form of a list in the column. It should be a list of the corresponding ids.

Is it a good approach to split every column into separate dynamic columns and then do a merge (in which case writing this merge statement is tricky for which I need some help)

but my question was is there any other way to achieve this directly, without splitting it?

If no, then how can we achieve dynamic merging?

PS: The no of values being entered in the columns domain and use_case is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
domain_map = domain_df.set_index('Domain_name')['Domain_id'].to_dict()
usecase_map = usecase_df.set_index('usecase_name')['id'].to_dict()

df = df.assign(
    domain_id=(
        df['Domain'].str.split(', ')
                    .map(lambda lst: list(map(domain_map.get, lst)))),
    usecase_id=(
        df['Use_case'].str.split(', ')
                      .map(lambda lst: list(map(usecase_map.get, lst)))),
)
```